# Exporting Row Data from a Large Text File Using R

Tags: r, text

I have a large text file with data from all 50 states in the US. Would like to cull the data down to New York State using R or Rstudio as I would like to get it geocoded. I can sort the data in the frame easily using Rstudio, but I can't get it into a separate text file from there.  I'm new to R and am obviously missing something fundamental.

The file is much larger than Excel can handle.  Filemaker 17 won't accommodate the delimiters used in the file "^". Selection in Sublime text was unwieldy and messed up my delimiters.

Tried to use write.csv - write.csv(variable, filename, row.names=F) - it confuses me as it doesn't seem to identify how the variable is pulled out of the file, and it gave various errors.  Not even sure if this is the best move.

Expect to simply pull about 200,000 records for the state of NY out of a flat text file (.txt) so I can have the data geocoded.  Can't do it.

Comment: Not sure if you already have the data in R or not? If yes, then you will need to subset the data before writing it using e.g. `xy[xy$state == "NY", ]`.

Comment: Thanks - I appreciate the quick response.  I really had no context to see this.  You definitely answered my question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the full dataset (let's call it `states`) in R as a data frame, you can then either create a separate subset of it or simply remove all states other than `NY` from it.

Subset:

```
ny <- states[states$state == "NY", ]
```

You create a new data frame here (`ny`) to work with.

Remove all states other than NY:

```
states <- states[states$state == "NY", ]
```

The difference here is that you simply overwrite your original data frame with the modified one.

If you have no need for states other than New York, then it would be better - in terms of memory - to overwrite the original data frame if you then intend to manipulate it in some way.

For example, changing values and/or the structure of the data frame will take up more memory because data frames that share identical data (i.e. unmodified subsets) simply point to the same copy of the data in that it exists in one memory sector and both the original data frame and the subset data frame point to it (the original object points to the whole data set, the subset points to only parts of it, thus saving memory (assuming it is unmodified, that is)).

It is only when you modify said subset that a separate copy is made, thus taking up more space.

If, however, you suspect that you will need to modify the other state data in future, I recommend creating a subset and working from that, using it as your source.